# reactstrap tooltip custom css not working

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, reactstrap

Anyone with experience on reactstrap package knows how can I change the color of the arrow and the opacity of the tooltip that appears? I tried several solutions but I can't find an answer.
My code looks like this :

```
<Tooltip
          autohide={false}
          className={styles.tooltip}
          innerClassName={styles.TextWithTooltip_tooltip}
          arrowClassName={styles.arrow}
          trigger="click hover focus"
          id={id}
          role="tooltip"
          placement="bottom"
          target={tooltipRef.current}
          toggle={toggle}
          isOpen={tooltipOpen}
        >
          {tooltipContent}
        </Tooltip>
```

I tried:

```
.TextWithTooltip {
  &_tooltip {
    border-radius: 10px !important;
    opacity: 0.5 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
    max-width: 580px !important;
    background-color: $white !important;
    color: $blue !important;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 1.56;
    padding: 18px 20px !important;
    box-shadow: 0 0 9px 4px rgba(214, 214, 214, 0.5);
    @media (max-width: $mobile-max-width) {
      max-width: 300px !important;
    }
  }

  &_icon {
    padding: 5px;
  }

  &_label {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: $blue;
    font-weight: 700;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    @media (max-width: $mobile-max-width) {
      font-size: 17px;
      max-width: 100%;
    }
  }
}

.tooltip-inner {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}

.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^="bottom"] .arrow::before {
  border-bottom-color: aqua !important; // default is #000;
}
```

but nothing works.
If anyone knows a solution for this, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I ran up the comment section on my answer lol. Make sure you're using `!important` in your SCSS files in order to override Bootstrap. This latest update should do the trick.

Comment: If the color on the arrow doesn't work, try setting a className on it like `.aqua-triangle` and then override using that selector. The `.tooltip-inner` should work just using that class selector and the `!important` keyword.

Comment: @ihodonald I don't know what's happening and why it doesn't work.. I've tried your solution and the styles doesn't apply.. just don't get it why, maybe it's a problem from the props applied to the component?

Comment: @ihodonald I found a clue now, if I put opacity: 0.5 !important; in &_tooltip (I've edited the post) it's working but only for values <= 0.9. I don't get why doesn't apply opacity: 1 !important;

Comment: The default is 1. I’ve never used &_ selectors before.

Comment: Here seems like the default it's 0.9 .. for example now when It must be 1, it sets himself to 0.9.. I'll dig next days for this solution, maybe it has to do something with those classNames props.. thank you very much for your time and help, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with CSS. If you don't want to change all tooltips globally, use CSS selectors.

Edit 1: You need to use the `border-bottom-color` for an arrow that points upwards. Check out this doc: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

Edit 1: You're using `.tooltip.inner` in your SCSS, which needs to be `.tooltip-inner`

Edit 2: You have to use `!important` to override *most* Bootstrap rules.

---

Arrow (with tooltip positioned at the bottom)

```
.bs-tooltip-bottom .arrow::before, .bs-tooltip-auto[x-placement^="bottom"] .arrow::before {
    border-bottom-color: aqua !important; // default is #000;
}
```

#### Result

[image]

---

Tooltip opacity

```
.tooltip-inner {
    opacity: .8 !important; // default is 1
}
```

#### Result

[image]

Comment: I tried your solution and it's not working, the styles are not applied. I don't understand why

Comment: @Christian Go here: https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/ then open up your Dev Tools, trigger a tooltip (make sure you are focused on the document, not the Dev Tools by clicking on the page), Hit F8 (for debugger), and inspect the tooltip itself (Ctrl + Shift + C). All reactstrap does is provide CSS rules to elements that are positioned using a library called Tether (not important for what you're doing). I've been doing it like this for years.

Comment: @Christian You may have to make some changes depending on where you are positioning the tooltip. This example assumes that your are using the tooltip positioned to the right.

Comment: in my project it's exactly like in your example, with opacity of 0.9 in .tooltip.show class. I tried exactly your example with placement="bottom" and it doesn't apply for neither one

Comment: I've updated the post to see how my scss file looks now

Comment: @Christian Updated with images.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220237/discussion-between-ihodonald-and-christian).